# How to properly render the same thing as drop down-list, but in selectbox?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, drop-down-menu

There's an array that looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => About us
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => Person 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => Person 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => Gallery
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => My CV
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Contact us
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [parent_id] => 6
                    [name] => Contactinfo
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [parent_id] => 6
                    [name] => My pictures
                )

        )

    [parents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 7
                )

        )

)
```

And there's a function I use to render data for drop-down menu:

```
// I render drop-down menu like this
echo buildMenu(0, $hierarchy)


function buildMenu($parentId, array $menuData) {
    $html = ''; 

    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId])) {

        $html = '<ul>'; 

        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) { 

            $html .= '<li><a href="#">' . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'] . '</a>'; 

            // find childitems recursively 
            $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData); 

            $html .= '</li>'; 
        }

        $html .= '</ul>'; 
    }

    return $html; 
}
```

This is working as expected. However right now I want to to turn drop down into a selectbox, so that an output would be like

```
<select>

  <option value="id1">Parent</option>
  <option value="id2">- Child 1</option>
  <option value="id2">-- Sub-Child 1</option>

</select>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show some effort by trying to solve it yourself. If you can not solve it, come back with a minimal code example of where you are stuck.

Comment: I need a suggestion where to start at least

Comment: I didn't say I need to start learning a language. I'd recommend you to write comments that make sense

Comment: Actully I meant what I wrote, in a kind way. I love to help, but this is not asking for help, it is asking for a solution to a challange you have not even shown the slighest effort to solve, this is why I concluded that you might need to learn some of the basics of PHP. With that in hand you should have been able to solve this yourself with minimal effort. Now all you got is a answer handed to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by modifying your current function as following

```
 function buildMenu($parentId, array $menuData) {
     $html = '';
     //static variable, shared across all (recursive in this context) calls of this function
     static $level = 1;

     if(isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId])) {

        if($level == 1)
            $html .= '<select>';

        foreach($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) {

           $html .= '<option value="__value_here__">' . str_repeat('--', $level - 1) . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'] . '</option>';

           //subsequent items will be indented one level
           $level++;

           $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);

           //recursive call has returned, so restore level
           $level--;
        }

        if($level == 1)
           $html .= '</select>';
     }

     return $html;
 }
```